# Error when Building gem5 : TypeError : File /hdd/Me/gem5/src/systemc/ext/systemc found where directory expected

Tags: scons, gem5

I got this error when building gem5 with this command : Scons/build/ARM/gem5.opt  :

TypeError : File /hdd/Me/gem5/src/systemc/ext/systemc found where directory expected.

I didn't have this problem before.

Comment: Best send an email to mailing list/create JIRA bug as well, and give your gem5 git SHA and operating system and GCC versions.

Comment: Thanks. I just removed the folder build : rm -r build. after that I used Scons build/ARM/gem5.opt again. It solved my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just removed the folder build:

rm -r build

then I built the gem5 again:

scons build/ARM/gem5.opt

It worked for me.